# Magento 2 get product attribute value of a multivalued field

Tags: php, magento2

I have a custom attribute called 'Color', which is a select box,

I have a instance of the product, and I want to get the selected value of my field 'Color'. The problem is when I try to do it its always returning null.

This is my code:

```
$product->getCustomAttribute('prj_color')
```

This is always `null`. But if I try to get a different field, which is not a multivalued field, a textbox for example, I can get the value normally.

I'm using Magento 2.1.5. Someone know whats going on?

Comment: Mh. Maybe try: `$product->getCustomAttribute('prj_color')->getValue(); `

Comment: The return of the call `$product->getCustomAttribute('prj_color')` is always null

Comment: Maybe because you have to actually wait for the user to select the value ? The object might be created when they select from the multivalued field.